# Getting clicked-on cell from grid in tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, tkinter-canvas

I'm new to Python and I have a project for my finals. It consist in the creation of a battleship game, and I would like to do something a little classy (with a GUI).

[I've made this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUmSf.png)

[And this aswell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSRmG.png)

So no problem with the GUI, the thing is , I request your help because I don't know how am I supposed to get the coordinates of every case of the board?

I would like to create a function that can return for example A,3 when I click on a case or I,9 , F,4 etc..

I've already created a function that give me X and Y positions but it's not really practical because even if I click outside the grid it give me a position outside the grid besides , it's even worse because in a same case it can return me 3 or 4 position and not only one take a look at this:

[On the Right Frame it give me position of the case clicked on the left grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsAao.png)

Here is the function I've made:

```
def donne_position(event):
    TexteC.delete("0.0",END)# on efface l'écriture précédente
    TexteC.insert(END,"clic detecte en x="+str(event.x) + " et y = " + str(event.y))
```

Also I would like to know how can I proceed to display a 5 cases ship (with circles for example) on the case of my board?

I'm using tkinter library but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: how are you creating the grid? Is it a bunch of buttons? Text widgets? Canvases? Is it a single canvas where you're drawing horizontal and vertical lines?

Comment: There pare two canvas but both are independent and are made the same way: a single canvas where I draw horizontal and vertical lines

Comment: It would help us if you created a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow, here's something to think about: You know how big your grid is in both of number of squares (not cases, case means something else in English) and the maximum X and Y coordinates. So think about what you can do to correlate those two pieces of information.

Regarding your second question (how can i proceed to display a 5 cases ship), it's too vague and is best if you first try to do it yourself (check out some tkinter tutorials if you haven't already) and then come back with specific problems you may be facing (as in "I have this piece of code, but instead of a circle it produces a hexagon, what's wrong with it?").